# Gaining shell access on a Unix Webserver

Tags: web-application, penetration-test, mysql, unix

I was pen testing an Unix web server for a challenge. I need to get root/shell access to the server & have got stuck at a point for quite a while now.

I have access to the web admin console but have not been able to find any RFI vulnerabilities.

Also I have gained access to the mysql database but the remote user does not have any file privileges, nor has permissions on the mysql database(has access to the application database only). The root user has no password set, but access is given only to localhost.

So, I am pretty much stuck at this point. Can anyone provide any ideas how to proceed next?

Comment: Have you gotten a shell yet?

Comment: Your title says 'escalation' but your question seems to be about getting a shell. You don't provide enough information to help us answer your question.

Comment: @John: No I don't have a shell yet

Comment: @schroeder: Thanks for pointing out the error. I have updated the title. Also there are so many details, if I posted them all the question would become very large. Please let me know the information that should be provided so that I can update the question.

Comment: @Neel That's kind of the point. Without more specific details, this question is too broad. If you can narrow down the problem, we might be able to help.

Answer (score 2):

Can you launch commands in a shell even with standard user privileges? Look what kernel has with `uname -r`. Maybe is vulnerable to [Dirty Cow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirty_COW) exploit, [affected kernels](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-protect-your-server-against-the-dirty-cow-linux-vulnerability). Or maybe you can use the old [Semtex exploit](https://github.com/realtalk/cve-2013-2094/blob/master/semtex.c). Always should be a directory to write... check for `/tmp`.

If you have access to the mysql, you can launch system commands from there using `\!`. Check [this](https://www.electrictoolbox.com/shell-commands-mysql-command-line-client/) out.

The post-exploitation is more difficult sometimes than the first intrussion! Be imaginative. Here are a lot of useful [commands](https://github.com/mubix/post-exploitation/wiki/Linux-Post-Exploitation-Command-List). Good luck!